venv is activated but pip installing still goes in default and python does not see the lib in sourcecode
in vscode in terminal shell typing "which python" shows default path:
C:\Users\erjan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
(my_venv)

but (my_venv) means my venv is active, I did pip install transformers, but the code below still shows error - can't see the lib.
# Use a pipeline as a high-level helper
from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline("summarization", model="facebook/bart-large-cnn")

How to fix it?

There is no way anyone can help without actual access to your setup. Delete the venv, downloaded model files, everything, and start again clean. Create venv, have a requirements.txt file with all packages, start by upgrading pip, install packages, download the models, and you should be good to go.

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78688317
